# How to parse this API return in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I'm trying to loop all the items in the product array.
Using an ajax call I get the following response from the API:

```
productData = {"product":[{"id":"9200000083451240","title":"Apple Lightning Cable"},{"id":"9200000098453451","title":"Apple iPhone XR"}],"totalResultSize":2}
```

As you can see the data I need is inside a variable "productData", how do I access it from my AJAX response data?

I've tried data.productData.product and some other stuff but nothing works.

```
    var searchTerm = $("#searchterm").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.com/search?term=' + searchTerm,
        type: 'GET',
    }).done(function (data) {
        $.each(data.productData.product, function (index, element) {
            console.log(element.title);
        });
        console.log('---- Data ----');
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you saying that the first code sample is what you're returning to the AJAX request? If so it's invalid; you need to remove the `productData =` from the start

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, the first code sample is the ajax call data payload. Simply stripping "productData =" is an option, but is that the way to go or should I handle this differently?

Comment: You will have to remove it, there is no other option. What you'r returning right now is not valid JSON. Also note that you're missing a comma between the properties in the first object of the array. Once you've fixed that change the loop to go through `data.product` and your logic will work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Allright! Guess I was thinking about it too much. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
productData = {"product":[{"id":"9200000083451240","title":"Apple Lightning Cable"},{"id":"9200000098453451","title":"Apple iPhone XR"}],"totalResultSize":2}
```

is not valid json response.

```
{"product":[{"id":"9200000083451240","title":"Apple Lightning Cable"},{"id":"9200000098453451","title":"Apple iPhone XR"}],"totalResultSize":2}
```

is valid json response and it can be get using :

```
// after success in ajax
.done(function (data) {
   console.log(data.product);   // More under it
   console.log(data.totalResultSize);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

to make your response **data** as a JS object , you have to call this function :

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');
```

source: [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)

to iterate objects inside a json object you may use $.each() function:

```
var obj = {
one: 1,
two: 2,
three: 3,
four: 4,
five: 5
};
$.each(obj, function (index, value) {
console.log(value);
});
```

source: [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Answer (score 0):

Stripped the "productData = " part in from of the API response (as suggested by Rory McCrossan) and then used JSON.parse (thanks sohaieb). I'm able to loop the products now. Thank you!